# Attach ChangeListener to multiple properties

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I do have a model which consists of multiple observable `SimpleDoubleProperty`, i now have a program which runs a function depending on changes on the observable properties.

I now do have a function calculateThings which gets called on changes:

```
public double calculateThings() {
  return getA() + getB() + getC();
}
```

For triggering that function i do attach a ChangeListener to every Property:

```
aProperty().addListener(observable -> calculateThings());
bProperty().addListener(observable -> calculateThings());
cProperty().addListener(observable -> calculateThings());
```

Is there a possiblity to add a ChangeListener to multiple properties in order to simplify the change listening? The Bindings API is not suitable here, the calculations are rather complex.

Like:

```
commonObservable().addListener(observable -> calculateThings());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Bindings API for arbitrarily complex computations, for example using a custom binding:

```
DoubleBinding computed = new DoubleBinding() {
    {
        super.bind(aProperty, bProperty, cProperty);
    }

    @Override
    public double computeValue() {
        return getA() + getB() + getC() ;
    }
};
```

or using the `Bindings.createXXXBinding(...)` utility methods:

```
DoubleBinding computed = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> getA() + getB() + getC(),
    aProperty, bProperty, cProperty);
```

In either case the binding will automatically update when any of the bound properties (`aProperty`, `bProperty`, or `cProperty` in the example) change, and you can either bind to `computed` or add listeners in the usual way:

```
someDoubleProperty.bind(computed);
computed.addListener((obs, oldComputedValue, newComputedValue) -> {
    /* some code */
});
```